# How to stop a form from refreshing even after submit / post

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form which does a 'post' to java code, on submit.
 The requirement is as follows - On submit an alert box should come with 'ok' button  where the user will read the info. and then click 'ok'.
This is just a info dialog, and nothing else.
 But the alert box should stay there until he clicks 'ok' button. 
I have given jquery submit and also tried form submit . The form is getting refreshed and alert box is going out of screen onsuccessful submit , as the entire form is getting posted and refreshes the screen.

Comment: We need to see your code to help you. Sounds like you need to use AJAX and/or prevent the default form submission

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the confirmation box, and prevent the default action if it isn't confirmed. See my comments in the code.

```js
$(function() {
  $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    if( !window.confirm('Do you want to send this form') ) { /* ask for confirmation */
      e.preventDefault(); /* if not confirmed, stop the default action, else send it */
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks.